# Given a homomorphism $\phi$, way to prove that $H \trianglelefteq G$ when $H \supset Ker\phi$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

To be more specific: Let $G$ be a group and let $G'$ be an *abelian* group. Let $\phi: G \mapsto G'$ be a group homomorphism, and let $K = \text{Ker}\phi$. Further, let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ containing $K$. Prove that $H  \trianglelefteq G$.

My professor provided an explanation that makes sense:

"It is sufficient to show that, if $ghg^{-1} \in H$, $\forall g \in G, h \in H$, then $H \trianglelefteq G$. Then, suppose $g \in G$ and $h \in H$.
\begin{align*}
ghgh^{-1}K &= (gH)(hK)(g^{-1}K)(h^{-1}K) \\
&= (gK)(hK)(gK)^{-1}(hK)^{-1} \\
&= (gK)(gK)^{-1}(hK)(hK)^{-1} \text{ since G/K is abelian }\\
&= (eK)(eK) \\
&= K 
\end{align*}
Therefore, $ghg^{-1}h^{-1} \in K$. Since $K \leq G$, $ghg^{-1}h^{-1} \in H$. Further, say $ghg^{-1}h^{-1} = h'$ for some $h' \in H$. Then, $ghg^{-1} = h'h \in H$."

MY QUESTION: This makes sense to me, but I am wondering if there is a way to use the fact that "A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is normal in $G$ if there is a group homomorphism $\psi: G \mapsto M$ such that $\ker\psi= H$." It seems to me that if you could find a way to show that $\ker\psi= H$ then this proof would be a lot easier. Perhaps this is not possible but I am asking the people on this forum as they are a lot smarter than I am. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the composite map $G\to G'\to G'/\phi(H)$, which you know makes sense because $G'$ is abelian.

Comment: Arturo's comment is the exact answer to your precise question, but another way to tell the same story is: $H  \trianglelefteq G$ because $H=\phi^{-1}(H')$ for some $H'\trianglelefteq G'$ (namely: $H'=\phi(H)$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Interesting. If you would care to explain in a bit more detail, I would love to hear it. I am just an undergrad so I don't think I fully understand your explanation but I do understand the direction you're headed.

Comment: The composite map is a group homomorphism with kernel $H$.